# How to get control to previous window while current window is open in c# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have two windows: `window1` and `window2`. When I click a button in `window1`, `window2` gets displayed.

How can I get focus/control onto `window1` without closing `window2`? I am working on c#.net wpf using VS 13

In Window1:

```
private void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 r = new Window2(s1);
    r.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Window2:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    static string data;

    public Window2(String a)
    {
        data=a;
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox.Text = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: put some code how you opened this window if it is showDialog() You cann't do this?

Comment: //In Window1  
private void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
            Window2 r = new Window2(s1);
            r.ShowDialog();
}

//In Window2
public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        static string data;
        public Window2(String a)
        {
            data=a;
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox.Text = data;
            
            
        }
    }

Comment: Don't post code in comment! Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference of `window1` to `window2` when you construct it.

Then from your `window2`, you can invoke the `Activate` method on `window1` to bring it to foreground again:

```
window1.Activate();
```

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate.aspx) of this method.

**EDIT:** Since you're using `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` (you didn't mention this information at first in your question), things are a bit different: ShowDialog is supposed to display the window as a [modal dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), and thus you **cannot** give the focus back to `window1` once `window2` is open, you have to close `window2` first.

I'm not sure what behavior you'd like to achieve, but you should try to use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`, and then use the `Activate` method as described above.

Comment: This isn't working.Can you suggest me another method

Comment: This is definitively working, and the correct way to do it. You are probably doing something wrong. But we can't help you more if you don't put at least some of your code in the question.

Comment: //In Window1 
private void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
Window2 r = new Window2(s1); 
r.ShowDialog(); 
} 
//In Window2 
public partial class Window2 : Window 
{ 
static string data; 
public Window2(String a) 
{ 
data=a; 
InitializeComponent(); 
TextBox.Text = data; 
} 
}

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
private void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 r = new Window2(s1);
    r.ShowDialog();
}
```

change the constructor of `Window2` add reference of `window1`

Something like this

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    static string data;
    static Window window1;
    public Window2(String a,Window parent)
    {
        data=a;
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox.Text = data;
        window1 = parent;
    }
}

and change that method to this

```
private void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 r = new Window2(s1, this);
    r.Show();
}
```

Now from `Window2` call this

```
window1.Activate();
```

from any method